# How can I remove part of the value sent to a hidden field and set a default state if the field is empty?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an image upload and crop function to add to a user form. Currently the user clicks on the change avatar button and it loads a modal window where they can upload there image and crop it. The jQuery below takes the new img src of the avatar and passes it to a hidden field so that it can be sent to the database.

The other part of the jQuery is for when the user goes back into the user page and it changes the img src of the avatar to what is displayed in the hidden field.

I need to make a few changes, firstly I need to change the url of the img src that is sent to the hidden field in the first place, currently it sends everything, i.e `http://www.mywebsite.com/img/avatars/user41.png` I only want it to send the filename, i.e `user41.png`

Secondly I need to change the on load function so it displays the right image when the user comes back to there user page, the path to the image is defined in the main site config file like below, because if I make the changes as described above, it will only have the filename to work from.

```
define( '_URL_AVATARS', '/img/avatars/' );
```

Thirdly I need to be able to set a default image if the hidden avatar field is blank - because the user hasn't uploaded anything yet. So it needs to be set to something like defaultpicture.png

jQuery:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".avatar-view > img").attr('src' ,$("#avatar-val").val());   });

 $('button').click(function () {
 $("#avatar-val").val($(".avatar-view>img").prop('src'));     });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="avatar-view" title="" data-original-title="Change the avatar">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block avatar-save">Change Avatar</button> 
  <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/img/avatars/user-41.png" alt="Avatar"></div>



<input name="avatar" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/img/avatars/user-41.png" id="avatar-val" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function () {
 var orig = $(".avatar-view>img").prop('src');
 var newVal = orig.replace(/^.*\//g,''); // strip path and domain before storing
 $("#avatar-val").val(newVal); // capture the modified value
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // set a default if necessary (assuming you've set the user's choice in #avatar-val, and that it will be empty or at least falsy if none was set:
  var myImage = $("#avatar-val").val() || "myDefaultImage.png";
  //included desired path in src. Probably better to use a config variable here rather than a hardcoded string, but you get the idea
  $(".avatar-view > img").attr('src' ,"/your/path/here/"+myImage);   
});
```